# TS2334 Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'. on app start only (ng-serve)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I'm having an issue when I start my angular app.

I have a function that does a post request, returns some data to my component and plots a chart. It works fine after I start the app do some random modification and save, but when I first start the app I get `Property 'length' does not exist on type 'Object'.`
on a for loop I have on my response array.

I've tried iterating through the response, only if it's not null, but that didn't work.

function:

```
dailyForecast() {
  var token = {token : "0a1b2c3d"};
  return this._http.post("https://www.improving.com.br/api/test/hits-by-browser", token)
  .map(result => result);
}
```

I get the error inside this for loop, but it works fine after I re-compile.

```
ngOnInit() {
  let chart = < any > {};
  this._weather.dailyForecast()
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      let browsers = [];
      let browsersAcesss = [];
      if (res !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          browsers.push(res[i][0]);
          browsersAcesss.push(res[i][1]);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Absolutely nothing here? https://www.google.nl/search?q=TS2334+Property+%27length%27+does+not+exist+on+type+%27Object%27

Comment: Have not found a thread where this problem only happens on initial build.

Comment: What does the data look like when it errors out? Is it changing? Check your network tab in dev tools.

Comment: what does `console.log(res);` return as the error occur

Comment: @FrankModica dev network tab shows a generic t=1539699003903 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @hana_wujira that line doesn't execute on start-up apparently. I think this is a typescript compile time error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to avoid the compile error you can set the response type to `any[]` or a custom interface.

```
ngOnInit() {
  let chart = < any > {};
  this._weather.dailyForecast()
    .subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      let browsers = [];
      let browsersAcesss = [];
      if (res !== null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
          browsers.push(res[i][0]);
          browsersAcesss.push(res[i][1]);
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use `Array.isArray(res)` it returns true if it contains array then you can use res.length